# Scrapy only returns limited amount of output

Tags: json, output, scrapy

I have a Spider that crawls several start_urls, but the problem is that I only receive a limited amount of output. When I crawl one start_url, however, it does return all the results before the infinite scrolling of the page. This is my Spider's code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Pinterest.items import PinterestItem

class PinterestSpider(Spider):
    name = "pinterest"
    allowed_domains = ["pinterest.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.pinterest.com/jetsetterphoto/pins/",
        "http://www.pinterest.com/llbean/pins/",        
        "http://www.pinterest.com/nordstrom/pins/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        pin_links = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='pinHolder']/a/@href").extract()
        repin_counts = hxs.xpath("//em[@class='socialMetaCount repinCountSmall']/text()").extract()
        like_counts = hxs.xpath("//em[@class='socialMetaCount likeCountSmall']/text()").extract()
        comment_counts = hxs.xpath("//em[@class='socialMetaCount commentCountSmall']/text()").extract()
        board_names = hxs.xpath("//div[@class='creditTitle']/text()").extract()
        pin_descriptions = hxs.xpath("//p[@class='pinDescription']/text()").extract()

        items = []
        for pin_link, repin_count, like_count, comment_count, board_name, pin_description in zip(pin_links, repin_counts, like_counts, comment_counts, board_names, pin_descriptions):
            item = PinterestItem()
            item["pin_link"] = pin_link.strip()
            item["repin_count"] = repin_count.strip()
            item["like_count"] = like_count.strip()
            item["comment_count"] = comment_count.strip()
            item["board_name"] = board_name.strip()
            item["pin_description"] = pin_description.strip()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I can see that the crawler does crawl the start_urls, but only returns 16 lines of output in a JSON file. When I use one start_url, it gives more lines of output (all of them, up to the infinite scrolling of the page). Is there maybe a limit set on the amount of requests I can do in settings? I tried looking for similar questions, but could not find any that is like mine. Any Ideas?

EDIT: Can it have something to do with the COncurrent Requests per DOmain setting??? http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html They specify here that the max is 8 and I get exactly 8 lines of output per domain. The total of concurrent requests is 16 by default so that would explain why I only get results of 2 start_urls. I will test if this works if I change the default (I have no idea if this makes sense to anyone else).

EDIT: I want to add this to my spider to extract basic info:

```
for BasicInfo in selector.css('div.userProfilePage'):
    item["company_pins"] = get(pin.css('div.PinCount::text'))
    item["company_likes"] = get(pin.css('ul.userStats li~ li+ li a::text'))
    item["company_name"] = get(pin.css('h1.userProfileHeaderName::text'))
    item["company_followers"] = get(pin.css('a.FollowerCount .buttonText::text'))
```

Then the code would be something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    selector = Selector(response)
    items = []
    for pin in selector.css('div.pinWrapper'):
        item = PinterestItem()            
        item["pin_link"] = get(pin.css('div.pinHolder a::attr(href)'))
        item["repin_count"] = get(pin.css('em.repinCountSmall::text'))
        item["like_count"] = get(pin.css('em.likeCountSmall::text'))
        item["comment_count"] = get(pin.css('em.commentCountSmall::text'))
        item["board_name"] = get(pin.css('div.creditTitle::text'))
        item["pin_description"] = get(pin.css('p.pinDescription::text'))

        items.append(item)
    self.log("extracted %d item(s) from %s" % (len(items), response.url))
    return items

def parse(self, response):
    selector = Selector(response)
    items = []
    for BasicInfo in selector.css('div.userProfilePage'):
        item["company_pins"] = get(pin.css('div.PinCount::text'))
        item["company_likes"] = get(pin.css('ul.userStats li~ li+ li a::text'))
        item["company_name"] = get(pin.css('h1.userProfileHeaderName::text'))
        item["company_followers"] = get(pin.css('a.FollowerCount .buttonText::text'))

items.append(item)
    self.log("extracted %d item(s) from %s" % (len(items), response.url))
    return items
```

I know this is wrong, but I dont know where or how to put it. Should I include a callback using request?

Comment: Maybe common problem of overriding `parse` method with `CrawlSpider`: you should avoid that unless you recreate `CrawlSpider`'s logic with rules and stuff. See warning here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the same problem when I use the normal Spider, it gives me the exact same output.

Comment: I edited the post, maybe that the default concurrent requests is the problem?

Comment: Apparently it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten your spider:

- looping on `<div class="pinWrapper">` elements,
- and using CSS selectors relatively to each `pin` (you can of course use relative XPath expressions, i.e. starting with ".//" instead of "//": `//div[@class='creditTitle']/text()` should be `.//div[@class='creditTitle']/text()`)

Note that `::text` and `::attr(attribute_name)` are extensions added by Scrapy to CSS selector syntax

The following code grabs 25 items per page:

```
import operator
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector, SelectorList
#from Pinterest.items import PinterestItem
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PinterestItem(Item):
    pin_link = Field()
    repin_count = Field()
    like_count = Field()
    comment_count = Field()
    board_name = Field()
    pin_description = Field()

def get(selectorlist):
    for i in selectorlist.extract():
        return i.strip()

class PinterestSpider(Spider):
    name = "pinterest"
    allowed_domains = ["pinterest.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.pinterest.com/jetsetterphoto/pins/",
        "http://www.pinterest.com/llbean/pins/",
        "http://www.pinterest.com/nordstrom/pins/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        items = []
        for pin in selector.css('div.pinWrapper'):
            item = PinterestItem()
            item["pin_link"] = get(pin.css('div.pinHolder a::attr(href)'))
            item["repin_count"] = get(pin.css('em.repinCountSmall::text'))
            item["like_count"] = get(pin.css('em.likeCountSmall::text'))
            item["comment_count"] = get(pin.css('em.commentCountSmall::text'))
            item["board_name"] = get(pin.css('div.creditTitle::text'))
            item["pin_description"] = get(pin.css('p.pinDescription::text'))
            items.append(item)
        self.log("extracted %d item(s) from %s" % (len(items), response.url))
        return items
```

Comment: Wow, this did the trick. I could never have figured this out by myself. Is it mainly a better choice to loop on elements (i.e. pinWrapper) instead of not doing that? Thank you very much!!

Comment: I find it easier to write and maintain that way, and when some data elements are missing in some of these XPath results, I wonder how `zip()` behaves

Comment: The highest level CSS selector for each "pin" would be `div.Grid > div.GridItems > div.item`. If the data you need is higher up in the document tree, you could extract it with other selectors outside of the "pin loop", and then use them to add some info to your items (same info for all items). I guess it all depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I delted my comment as I didnt provide enough info. I was figuring out how to use it in the mean time. I edited my inital question, is this the way to go or? ps. the BasicInfo I just made up to illustrate what i want to crawl